# part of dataframe in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe and I want to plot it with ggplot:

```
ggplot(newlevels, aes(dates)) + 
geom_line(newlevels$levels, aes(y=levels), colour="red") + 
geom_line(newlevels$mean, aes(y=newlevels$mean), colour="green") + 
geom_line(newlevels$levelSMA,aes(y=newlevels$levelSMA), colour="blue")
```

But, I want to plot only [1:100] lines of the dataframe, can I do it directly with ggplot without creating a new dataframe which is dataframe[1:100]?
I cannot find the syntax to plot a part of data from dataframe.
Thanks.

Comment: Just subset the dataframe when you pass it to ggplot: `ggplot(newlevels[1:100,], aes(dates))`

Comment: `ggplot` does not have a subsetting option. It assumes you've properly manipulated/subset your data before plotting. Also you really shouldn't use "$" inside `aes()` statements if the columns re coming from the passed data.frame. When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This has been addressed by @agstudy and @pmcs ...
@divibisan, i think you need the `c(1:100)`

For your particular dataframe, you would include this:

```
ggplot(newlevels[c(1:100), ], aes(x,y))+geom_points()+...
```

Comment: If you're only using a single range, you don't need the `c()`. `1:100` returns the same thing as `c(1:100)`. If you want more than just one range, of course, you need the `c()`.

Comment: Thanks!  I suppose I am more conservative in coding sets! :)

Comment: That's fine! It actually is probably safer to include it, just in case you do want to add another row later, but it's not strictly necessary.